# How to send msg's back to a client in a Scala Server

Tags: scala, match, server, message

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import java.util._


object Server2{

def displayUsageInfo = {
    println("Parameters are:");
    println("  1) The port number that the server will listen on")
}

def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
    if(args.length != 1) {
        displayUsageInfo
    } 
    else {
        try {
            val sock=new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args(0)))
            var finished = false
            while (!finished){
                println("waiting");
                val connection=sock.accept()
                println("connection from " + connection.getRemoteSocketAddress())

                val is = connection.getInputStream()  
                val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
                var line = in.readLine

                while (line!=null && !finished) {
                    line match {
                        case "quit" => finished = true
                        case _ => println("Received " + line)
                    }
                if(line == "<gia-sou/>"){
                    printf("he"); //here!!!!!!!!!!
                }

                    if(!finished){
                        line = in.readLine
                    }
                }
                connection.close
            }
        } catch {
            case e:BindException =>
                println("Cannot bind to port. Is a server already running?")
            case e:NumberFormatException =>
                println("Port number should be an integer")
            case e:IllegalArgumentException =>
                println("The port number needs to be less than 65536")
            case ex:Throwable => println("Exception: " +ex.toString())
        }
    }
}
}
```

I understand my knowledge on Scala is very low, I'm very new to this still. I would like to know when my server receives a message from the client, how do I send a message back? The place id like to put the message is where is say 'here'. 
Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever java provides, that is a [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

```
val connection=sock.accept()
println("connection from " + connection.getRemoteSocketAddress())
val printWriter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream, true)
printWriter.println("Whatever message you like")
```

Comment: I get an error saying " 'error:not found: type PrinterWriter "

Comment: @CallumSangray Sorry a typo, should be `PrintWriter` not PrinterWriter